# how to get all parents and all children(contain all children or grandchildren etc..) in one AQL

Tags: arangodb

my graph is as follow:

```
 A -> B -> C ->D
   \> E -> F -> G
       \>  H -> I- J - ...
```

and when I select **H** node, i want to get his all parent **A,E** and all childs **I,J...**

The result I am looking forward to is **A,E,H,I,J...**

i use two AQL in JAVA, some code is as follows:

**fahters:**

```
FOR v,e,p IN 1..9999 INBOUND  'xx/xx' xxGraph
RETURN e
```

**childs:**

```
FOR v,e,p IN 1..999999999 OUTBOUND  'xx/xx' xxGraph
RETURN e
```

and finally merge fathers and childs.

as you can see,i must **execute twice** , can I **execute once** and get **same result**?

I read the documentation and didn't find a suitable method. Maybe I missed it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For some graphs, the `ANY` traversal direction modifier might work, but here it would also follow the parent's outgoing edges (`E -> F -> G` and `B -> C -> D`) which you do not want to be included in the result.

You can do both the `INBOUND` and the `OUTBOUND` traversal in a single AQL query by using sub-queries, then combine their results:

```
LET start = 'vert/H'
LET parents = (FOR v IN 0..9999 INBOUND start edge RETURN v)
LET children = (FOR v IN 1..9999 OUTBOUND start edge RETURN v)
RETURN APPEND(REVERSE(parents[*]._key), children[*]._key)
```

Note the minimal traversal depth of 0 for the parents. This will include the start vertex `H`. I use `REVERSE()` to inverse the order of the parent documents, so that `A` and `E` come first. `APPEND()` concatenates the elements of both arrays (here just the document keys).

https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/examples-combining-queries.html

Comment: @CoDEmanX - In the AQL query, shoudn't `start edge` be just `start` in both instances?

Comment: @peak `start` is the start vertex and `edge` is the edge collection for traversing an anonymous graph. If you have a named graph then you would do `start GRAPH 'xxGraph'`. Either way, it is necessary to specify edge collections, either directly or via a named graph definition.